# Unable to configure SSL on port 4001 in Apache2

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2

I'm trying to configure apache2 with SSL on port 4001, I have done the following so far:

ports.conf

```
Listen 4001
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 4001
</IfModule>
```

default-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:4001>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile myfile.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile myfile.key
</VirtualHost>
```

After that, I restarted the service; I was able to access the website just through http, https was not working yet.

Then, I run:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now, the service is not able to start likely due to the previous commands.

Does anyone know what else I have to do to configure SSL on port 4001?

Comment: Are you trying to have Apache listen twice on the same port, once for http and once for https?

Comment: No, I just need https

Comment: Remove the extra `Listen 4001`.